# Make a table for a function that varies depending on the argument ranges

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to create a `Table` for the value of a function $f(x,y)$, the form of which changes depending on the ranges of $x$ and $y$. For instance, $f=x+y$ for $x\in [1,2]$ and $y\in [0,1]$ while $f=x-y$ for $x\in [2,3]$ and $y\in [1,2]$.

I tried the following code, which didn't work.

```
Flatten[Table[{{x + y, x, y}, {x, 1, 2, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}}, {{x - y, x, y}, {x, 2, 3, 0.1}, {y, 1, 2, 0.1}}], 1] // TableForm
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just define your function as a piecewise function and build the table of values as normal?

Comment: @KevinAusman: Thanks! Since this code is part of a larger project, I'm seeking a solution that uses the current format as much as possible. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to salvage your attempt to get the values in the form I believe you were trying to get them in:

```
spec = {
   {{x + y, x, y}, {x, 1, 2, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}},
   {{x - y, x, y}, {x, 2, 3, 0.1}, {y, 1, 2, 0.1}}
   };
Flatten[Table @@@ spec, 1]
```

But this question also brings to mind `Piecewise`, which can be used to express functions like the one in your question:

```
f = Piecewise[{
   {x + y, 1 <= x < 2 && 0 <= y < 1},
   {x - y, 2 <= x <= 3 && 1 <= y <= 2}
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can now get the table of values like this:

```
values = Table[f, {x, 1, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2, 0.1}];
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works!